# Python Websocket Server does not work when containerized (docker)

Tags: python-3.x, docker, websocket

I have the following code for a full duplex python websocket server.

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import os
import json
import time
import socket
import threading

def get_config_key(key):
        value = os.environ.get(key)
        print("[Agent] get_config_key. Key: '{0}'. Value: '{1}'".format(key, value))
        if value:
            return value
        else:
            return ""

    class Agent_Server_Test:

        def __init__(self):
            print("[Agent_Server_Test] Starting Agent '{}'".format(self))

            self.producer_message = ""
            self.producer_flag = threading.Event()

            agent_worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_worker_websocket)
            agent_worker_thread.start()
            test_loop = threading.Thread(target=self.test_periodic)
            test_loop.start()

        def run_worker_websocket(self):
            agent_url = self.get_agent_url()
            print("[Agent_Server_Test] run_worker_websocket started for agent_url '{}'".format(agent_url))
            agent_worker_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
            asyncio.set_event_loop(agent_worker_loop)
            self.agent_websocket = websockets.serve(self.worker_connection_handler, host = agent_url["host"], port = agent_url["port"])
            agent_worker_loop.run_until_complete(self.agent_websocket)
            agent_worker_loop.run_forever()

        def get_agent_url(self):
            agent_url = { "is_agent_url": True, "host" : "0.0.0.0", "port" : 8889}
            print("[Agent_Server_Test] Returning agent url '{}'.".format(agent_url))
            return agent_url

        async def worker_connection_handler(self, websocket, path):
            print("[Agent_Server_Test] worker_connection_handler activated.")
            worker_recv_task = asyncio.create_task(self.worker_recv_handler(websocket, path))
            worker_send_task = asyncio.create_task(self.worker_send_handler(websocket, path))
            done, pending = await asyncio.wait([worker_recv_task, worker_send_task], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED,)
            for task in pending:
                task.cancel()

        async def worker_recv_handler(self, websocket, path):
            print("[Agent_Server_Test] worker_recv_handler start.")
            async for message in websocket:
                print("[Agent_Server_Test] worker_recv_handler. Received message from Worker: '{}'".format(message))
                self.producer_message = message
                self.producer_flag = True

        async def worker_send_handler(self, websocket, path):
            print("[Agent_Server_Test] worker_send_handler start.")
            while True:
                message = await self.producer()
                print("[Agent_Server_Test] worker_send_handler. Sending message '{}'".format(message))
                await websocket.send(json.dumps(message))

        async def producer(self):
            print("[Agent_Server_Test] Waiting for producer_flag.")
            self.producer_flag.wait()
            print("[Agent_Server_Test] producer flag set to true. Activating producer.")
            self.producer_flag.clear()
            return self.producer_message[::-1]

        def test_periodic(self):
            print("[Agent_Server_Test] test_periodic started.")
            test_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
            asyncio.set_event_loop(test_loop)
            count = 0
            while True:
                test_loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(30)) 
                print("[Agent_Server_Test] test_periodic run '{}', every 30sec.".format(count))
                self.producer_message = "Test_Periodic_Message" + str(count)
                self.producer_flag.set()
                count = count+1

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        try:
            #app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int("5000"), debug=True)
            agent = Agent_Server_Test()

        except Exception as e:
            print("[Agent_Server_Test] !!!ERROR!!! EXCEPTION OCCURED IN PROXY TOP LEVEL:'{}'. Exit.".format(e))
```

I have the following code to connect to test connecting and sending a message to it. The remote_ip is hardcoded for when I deploy the server as a docker container on an EC2 instance.

```
    import asyncio
import websockets
import os
import json
import time
import socket
import threading

class Agent_Server_Client:

        #agent_server_uri = "ws://localhost:8889"    #local
        agent_server_uri = "ws://<REMOTE_IP>.:8889"    #remote

        def __init__(self):
            asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(self.test())

        async def test(self):
            print("[Test_Agent_Server_Client] Starting test")
            async with websockets.connect(self.agent_server_uri) as websocket:
                print("[Test_Agent_Server_Client] Sending Test Msg")
                await websocket.send("Test Message")
                response = await websocket.recv()
                print("[Test_Agent_Server_Client] Received response: {}".format(response))
                return response

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        try:
            #app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int("5000"), debug=True)
            agent = Agent_Server_Client()

        except Exception as e:
            print("[Test_Agent_Server_Client] !!!ERROR!!! EXCEPTION OCCURED IN PROXY TOP LEVEL:'{}'. Exit.".format(e))

When testing the local version, I get the expected response and print outs from the agent.

    [Test_Agent_Server_Client] Starting test
    [Test_Agent_Server_Client] Sending Test Msg
    [Test_Agent_Server_Client] Received response: "65egasseM_cidoireP_tseT"

    [debug] # [Agent] worker_connection_handler activated.
    [debug] # [Agent] worker_connection_handler tasks created.
    [debug] # [Agent] worker_recv_handler start.
    [debug] # [Agent] worker_send_handler start.
    [debug] # [Agent] Waiting for producer_flag.
    [debug] # [Agent] producer flag set to true. Activating producer.
    [debug] # [Agent] worker_send_handler. Sending message: '46egasseM_cidoireP_tseT'
    [debug] # [Agent] Waiting for producer_flag.
```

When I test the remote version, I get the following response and only one print:

```
[Test_Agent_Server_Client] Starting test
[Test_Agent_Server_Client] Sending Test Msg
[Agent_Server_Client] !!!ERROR!!! EXCEPTION OCCURED IN PROXY TOP LEVEL:'code = 1011 (unexpected error), no reason'. Exit.

[[[21-08-19 09:55:49] Agent [debug] # [Agent] worker_connection_handler activated.   │
```

I think the docker container has something to do with it.
The Dockerfile is

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine3.8
RUN pip3 install websockets
COPY . /agent
WORKDIR /agent
EXPOSE 8889
CMD ["python", "agent.py"]
```

And I deploy it to the EC2 instance using Ansible as follows:

```
---
- hosts: swarm_manager_main
  become: true
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - "vars/{{ env }}.yml"
  tasks:
    - name: get public_ip4 output
      shell: curl http://EC2_IP/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4 
      register: public_ipv4
    - debug: 
        var: public_ipv4.stdout
    - name: Create docker_pull
      template:
        src: templates/docker_pull_agent.j2
        dest: /root/pull_agent.sh
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: 0644
    - name: Pull containers
      command: "sh /root/pull_agent.sh"
    - name: (re)-create the agent
      docker_container:
        name: agent
        image: registry.gitlab.com/core/v2/agent
        state: started
        exposed_ports: 8889
        published_ports: 8889:8889
        recreate: yes
        env:
          HOST_MACHINE: "{{ public_ipv4.stdout }}"
```

I am not entirely sure why it does not work. I can see the connection is started but it fails, I assume due to the docker container. Any clue where my mistake lies?

Comment: I tried to run your code in my local machine and it gets the exception with "name threading is not defined"

Comment: To shorten the code, I did not include the imports or all the code
The imports are,

import asyncio
import websockets
import os
import json
import time
import socket
import threading

from logger import Logger

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is not with AWS's security groups? What does it print on the server side?

Comment: @7_R3X I don't think so, as he got the error message. If it was security group, request wouldn't reach to socket server.

Comment: @RafafTahsin How do you know it reached the server socket? The error message is on the client side, as far as I understood the question.

Comment: @7_R3X ... you are right.

Comment: Added imports. Any clue on how to figure it out with the security groups?
Websockets is a third party module: https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html

Comment: @SvenAkkermans: Modify your server code to print something everytime a connection is made, redeploy the application, make a connection and monitor the server console logs. Also, if you have access to the AWS console, check the security group settings and see if it allows the inbound traffic on port 8889. By default, it doesn't.

Comment: The EC2 is configured correctly (8889 tcp 0.0.0.0/0 is an inbound rule).
I am unsure on how to do the first part of your suggestion: I already print every time the worker_connection_handler method is activated

Comment: @SvenAkkermans: Is your client running from behind a proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue:
the docker container uses Python 3.6. My local environment Python 3.7.
Asyncio only supports asyncio.create_task in 3.7. 
The independent solution is changing the code to:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
worker_recv_task = loop.create_task(self.worker_recv_handler(websocket, path))
worker_send_task = loop.create_task(self.worker_send_handler(websocket, path))
```